# Using a remote in Av mode using a Canon EOS T4i

Tags: remote, aperture-priority, canon-650d

I want to use an infrared remote to trigger my Canon EOS T4i for a self-portrait.  Can this be done in Aperture priority (Av) mode or only in Manual mode?

Comment: Have you read the manual to your Canon?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an infrared remote, such as the RC-6 or its generic clones, with either Aperture Priority, Manual, or any other exposure mode with your EOS Rebel T4i/650D.

The key considerations are to use the *Self Timer* drive mode to enable the remote and insure that the camera is either pre-focused manually to the correct subject distance or the selected AF point(s) is(are) aimed at where you'll be.

So while you don't need to necessarily use manual *exposure* mode, it is useful to use manual *focus* instead of auto focus.